Resultado de los select con "punto" para decimales
He cambiado de motor sql server, de TOAD a Microsoft SQL Server.
El caso es que ahora los select con decimales me los devuelve con punto cuanod TOAD me los devolvia con "coma".
No encuentro donde cambiar esta opcion.
¿¿Hay algun comando que pueda añadir a la query para cambiar la configuracion del idioma??

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No cambiaste de motor.. TOAD no es un motor, es una ide para conectarse a una base de datos... ahora, cambiaste a cual ide? y en esa ide, no es necesario, nunca, cambiar el separador.. porque en realidad, le podes decir en la query como queres que muestre las cosas. Suena a que estas confundiendo conceptos y es grave...
